# won't print out all of the strings

Tags: ruby

I am in a coding bootcamp so I am really brand new to all of this and I was wondering why when I run this code it will only print the first two spots of the array?

```
words = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Yes", "No"]

index = 0.to_i
while index.to_i < words.length
  p words[index.to_i]
  index = index.to_s + 1.to_s
end
```

Comment: Because that's not how you increment numbers (casting them to strings and gluing strings together). Print your `index` after you "increment" it, you'll see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because of

```
index = index.to_s + 1.to_s
```

`to_s` converts the receiver to a string, i.e. `0` becomes `"0"` and `1` becomes `"1"`. Calling [`+`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/String.html#method-i-2B) on strings concatenates them, i.e. `"0" + "1"` becomes `"01"`.

That one is fine, because `"01".to_i` is still `1`. However, on the next iteration you get `"01" + "1"` which becomes `"011"` and `"011".to_i` is `11` which is more than the array's length.

To fix your code, you just have to remove the conversion and stick to integers:

```
words = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Yes", "No"]

index = 0
while index < words.length
  p words[index]
  index = index + 1
end
```

You can also let Ruby handle the index for you via [`each_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#each_index-method):

```
words.each_index do |index|
  p words[index]
end
```

or without an index via [`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Array.html#each-method):

```
words.each do |word|
  p word
end
```

Comment: If the index is really needed, there's also [#each_with_index](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.5.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-each_with_index).

Comment: thank you for the help I find myself overthinking things and I think that's what I did there I did remove the conversions and it ran perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Ruby so I'm not sure about syntax.
But I can solve your logic.

```
words = ["Hello", "Goodbye", "Yes", "No"]

index = 0.to_i
while index.to_i < words.length
  p words[index.to_i]
  index = index.to_i + 1
end
```

This shall work.
Logic is this :

1. while index is less than length keep looping
2. print words[index]
3. increment index by 1 so that it moves to next position.